# What is this IC "D4164D"

Tags: components, identification, through-hole

I found this component lying about, anybody have any idea what it is? I found a few people selling them on ebay but no description.
The label says, "NEC 208 D4164D"
[image: Top View]
[image: Side View]

Thanks,

Comment: static ram I think https://www.donberg.ie/catalogue/semiconductors/semiconductors_c-d/d_4164d.html

Comment: Yup, looks like CMOS SRAM. The TI part number is TMS4164 if you want to look at a datasheet.

Comment: It is NMOS and a dynamic, not static RAM. organized as 64k x 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a 64k by 1-bit Dynamic RAM.

Not much value these days - over 30 years old. The date code may be 1982 week 8.

I designed similar devices into products in 1983.

This is not the NEC part but probably pin compatible [64K DRAM datasheet](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/6600to6699/pdf/nte6664.pdf).

EDIT - As pointed out by Lawrence I misread the part number and added a 4. This is a 64k by 1 DRAM that is a bit earlier than the 64kx4 part.

Comment: You linked to the 41464 -- the 64Kx4 in the 18-pin package.  OP included a photo of a 4164 (64K x 1 ) in the 16-pin DIP.

Comment: @Lawrence - oops. Yes I misread the number.  I have corrected the answer. Thanks